# Laravel 5.4 redirection to custom url after login

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I am using Laravel Framework 5.4.10, and I am using the regular authentication that

```
php artisan make:auth
```

provides. I want to protect the entire app, and to redirect users to /themes after login.

I have 4 controllers: ForgotPasswordController.php, LoginController.php, RegisterController.php and ResetPasswordController.php. I have edited this line into the last three:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/themes';
```

This is the first line in my routes/web.php:

```
Auth::routes();
```

I have added this function in my Controller.php:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

    }
```

I have edited app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php, so that the handle function looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/themes');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

It's all fine, except when I click the Login button, I get redirected to "/", not "/themes". If I don't require authentication in the controllers (no __contruct function in Controller.php file), I get redirected OK at login. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/redirect-to-profile-after-login?page=1&replyId=174180

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You need to add the following lines into your **LoginController**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
if ( $user->isAdmin() ) {// do your magic here
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}

 return redirect('/home');
}
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
//protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
}
```

Comment: Great! The only thing is that isAdmin() gave me a BadMethodCallException, so I skipped the whole IF part and it worked perfectly!

Comment: I am glad it helped, my application uses isAdmin() to check wether the user is an Admin  before redirection, could'nt have the chance to change according your code just wanted to give you a hint. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't it be possible also to obtain the authenticated user with the Auth facade?, import it with `use Auth;` and then to obtain user you would do `$user = Auth::user();`.

Answer (score 18):

If you look in the AuthenticatesUsers trait you will see that in the sendLoginResponse method that there is a call made to `$this->redirectPath()`.  If you look at this method then you will discover that the redirectTo can either be a method or a variable.

This is what I now have in my auth controller.

```
public function redirectTo() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    switch(true) {
        case $user->isInstructor():
            return '/instructor';
        case $user->isAdmin():
        case $user->isSuperAdmin():
            return '/admin';
        default:
            return '/account';
    }
}
```

Comment: Redirecting using access roles can be done this way using the Bouncer library as well (for those not writing there own access control methods). Just  change "case $user->isInstructor():" to "case Bouncer::allows('isInstructor', $user):". You will obviously need to have the 'isInstructor' ability added to the users role. If anyone wants me to post the Bouncer code I use in my controller let me know.

Comment: This is much cleaner. You are amazing!

Comment: Are the isAdmin(), etc. methods already defined by Laravel or did you have to define them ?

Comment: @MasonH.Hatfield You have to define them for your application. You can also use other methods of handling this, such as the above comment from AKMorris about [Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer).

Answer (score 17):

The way I've done it by using AuthenticatesUsers trait.

`\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

Add this method to that controller:

```
/**
 * Check user's role and redirect user based on their role
 * @return 
 */
public function authenticated()
{
    if(auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))
    {
        return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
    } 

    return redirect('/user/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: What if i want redirect it only when the user is authenticated trough the web instead of api jwt?

Answer (score 5):

[Path Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication) (tested in laravel 7)
When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the `/home` URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect path using the HOME constant defined in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

Answer (score 4):

For newer versions of Laravel, please replace `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;` with `protected $redirectTo = '/newurl';` and replace `newurl` accordingly.

Tested with Laravel version-6

Answer (score 1):

You should set $redirectTo value to route that you want redirect

```
$this->redirectTo = route('dashboard');
```

inside AuthController constructor.

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    $this->redirectTo = route('dashboard');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Providers->RouteServiceProvider.php
2. There change the route, given below:

   ```
   class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/dashboard';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In AuthenticateUsers.php, override the authenticate method

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    //
    if($user->guard == 'web')
    {
        
        return redirect('/themes');
    }
    
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add method in LoginController add line `use App\User;` on Top, after this  add method, it is work for me wkwkwkwkw  , but you must add    `{{ csrf_field() }}` on view admin and user

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user){

$user=User::where('email',$request->input('email'))->pluck('jabatan');
$c=" ".$user." ";
$a=strcmp($c,' ["admin"] ');

if ($a==0) {
    return redirect('admin');

}else{
    return redirect('user');

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

in accord with [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#included-routing), I create in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php the following method :

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user=Auth::user();

    if($user->account_type == 1){
        return '/admin';
    }else{
        return '/home';
    }

}
```

to get the user information from my db I used "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;".

Answer (score 0):

For those using Laravel 8 or newer, you can create a custom controller for the login.
I am making tweaks to @plexus's answer here on this same question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45529876/7880201)

The $redirectTo can be a variable or a function. In my case, I choose to go the function way.

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
// protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

public function redirectTo() {
    $role_id = Auth::user()->role_id; 
    switch ($role_id) {
    
      case Role::GENERAL_DEFAULT_ROLE:
        return route('home');
        break;
    
    case Role::MAINTENANCE_ROLE:
        return route('mtn_home');
        break;

    case Role::HSE_ROLE:
        return route('hse_home');
        break;
  
      default:
        return '/home'; 
      break;
    }
  }
```

Then in your (custom) login function, you can do

return redirect($this->redirectPath());

The above line would simply redirect users to their routes when they login. As simple as that.

See the example below:

```
// The login logic
public function login(Request $request)
{
    

    // blah blah blah
    // but don't forget to call the redirect function while passing the path to redirect to which 
    // is found by calling $this->redirectPath() function.
    
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    
    
}
```