# Redirect to Custom URL after Registration in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redirect, laravel-authentication

I am working on cart in laravel 5.5. Whenever guests click on "Add to cart", i am redirecting to login. If they have account, they will login and redirecting to product info they have selected. Otherwise they are registering. **I wanted to redirect to customer selected product after registration.** 
For Login, this is working fine..  return redirect()->intended();
For Registration intended url not working..

Comment: Please put some code here

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: put it in session fetch it after registering

Comment: I tried this after login..  return redirect()->intended(); It is working fine. But i don't know how to achieve this after registration.

Comment: I am new to laravel. Can you please sample code for this. @GauravGupta

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 redirection to custom url after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login)

Comment: I am asking about custom dynamic url after registration only @AmarjitSingh

Comment: override the `redirectTo` method in `App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController`

Comment: Tried it, but I am not able to get that selected product URL. @ABDEL-RHMAN

Comment: alright, try to override `registered` method and use `return redirect()->intended();`

Comment: I tried this. But it is giving error like this. **Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected** @ABDEL-RHMAN

Comment: @Sridhar i tried that and it worked for the `registered` method and gives the same error for the `redirectTo` method did you remvoe it?

Comment: I don't have registered method. Can you please share code of your registered method. @ABDEL-RHMAN

Comment: first remove the `redirectTo` methd then implement the `registered` method in `RegisterController` like so `public function registered(){return redirect()->intended();}`

Comment: Awesome.. It is working.. Thank you so much.. @ABDEL-RHMAN

Answer (score 13):

In Controllers/Auth/RegisterController
change `protected $redirectTo = '/';` at line 30

For dynamic URL replace `protected $redirectTo = '/';` with

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    /* generate URL dynamicaly */.
    return '/path'; // return dynamicaly generated URL.
}
```

you can also use `return redirect()->intended(/* default uri to redirect user goes here */);`

The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I wanted this redirect location to be dynamic based on product name clicked by guest after registration.

Comment: Just read Laravel documentation here  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication

Comment: I tried this. But it is giving error like this.  **Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected**

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Your can use this method

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $userName = Auth::user()->name;
    //use your own route
    return route('user.edit', compact('userName'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  `function registered(Request $request, $user)` as follows

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($redirect_to_selected_prodcut) {
            return redirect('/order/product');
        }

        return redirect()->intended();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the code that does the login add

```
 return \Redirect::intended('/default-url-if-user-did-not-come-from-any-page');
```