# Redirect page after login using php framework laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to show a page from myController after successful to login.

```
$email = $req->input('username');
$pass = $req->input('password');
$login = DB::table('for_login')->where(['E_mail'=>$email, 'Password'=>$pass])->get();
if(count($login)>0) {              
    return view('frontEnd.Home');
} else {
    echo "Invalid username/password";
}
```

How can I redirect a page after a successful login?

[image: delAction]

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and what your exact problem is?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: any reason you are not using the auth system and out of the box login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 redirection to custom url after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login)

Comment: Word of advice, head over to laracasts.com, find tutorial about authentication in laravel. It will save you a lot of headache :)

Comment: In the error above, the problem is not redirect after successful, the problem is that whatever route you are calling does not accept a get request, my guess you have to change that route to post.

Comment: can you please share your route??

Comment: and be sure your home.blade.php is upnder the frontEnd directory? check for typo.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile the OP is not using the default Auth system in Laravel ... not a duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Go to AuthController.php and add authenticated method'

```
protected function authenticated($request){
    return view('frontEnd.home');
}
```

The built-in authentication functionality of laravel looks for authenticated method upon successful login and performs it, if it is declared. Hope this helps.

Comment: i don't use laravel built-in login/registration

Answer (score -2):

use 
header("location:page.php");