# Laravel force redirect after user log in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am building an app that I require that after a user successfully logins goes to a page if a session var is NOT set where based on some input data from the user this session var will be filled. After this I will pass the intended url to window.location.href in JS to redirect. So far I can only find responses as how to add

> protected $redirectTo = “/something”

Can someone share some light please.

Comment: See this, hope it helps!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login

Comment: Do you need a JS redirect? Like after success AJAX or so...

Comment: Setup a middleware to check for the session and then wrap a Route::group() around all routes that require authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Hiren Gohel I was trying to do the same solution pointed on your link but I forgot to add return before the redirect. the following code works

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
    return redirect('/setup');
}
```

on Auth/LoginController.php