# Setting up roles and permissions in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, permissions, roles

My current project for college is a school management system. It consists mainly of three "profiles" - one for students, another for teachers/professors and a third for coordinators/admins.

After authentication and leaving the login page, this is what I'd like to happen:

- If users occupy only one role inside the application, they should be redirected directly to the correspondent profile (e.g.: a student goes straight to a student profile);
- However, for those who occupy two or even all three roles (unlikely but possible), an *identities* page gives them a choice between their different profiles;
- A user can only have access to pages and profiles as defined by their role(s);

What would be the best way to implement this within Laravel 5.6?

Note: I can currently authenticate users but no permissions and roles are in place. I'm using Laravel's default *users* table.

Comment: people told below but when i am using entrust i was so happy. Great package. After that i found the voyager admin package and my life getting easier. You can do anything you told.

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: @AdamKozlowski I haven't had time yet to test the solutions offered here, but I'll do it later today. I will update the post as soon as I do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use **ENTRUST (Laravel 5 Package)**

Simple and powerful.

In order to install Laravel 5 Entrust, just add the following to your composer.json. Then run composer update:

```
"zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
```

Open your config/app.php and add the following to the providers array:

```
Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
```

In the same config/app.php and add the following to the aliases array:

```
'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class,
```

Run the command below to publish the package config file `config/entrust.php:`

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Open your config/auth.php and add the following to it:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Namespace\Of\Your\User\Model\User::class,
        'table' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

If you want to use Middleware (requires Laravel 5.1 or later) you also need to add the following:

```
'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,
```

to routeMiddleware array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

Read more and get the library: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: As in his example there are only 3 roles that means they can be used as permissions and therefore there is really no need for extra package for such simple task

Comment: It is a complex library for this kind of task. If you have never used that - just try and see how it simple is.

Comment: I'm just thinking it's an overkill for him to add it and learn it (no matter how easy it is) if task is actually very simple

Comment: Let him make his own decision

Comment: I chose your answer because it addresses the problem I have, even though I'd have to spend some time learning how to use it. I'll first try without a package, using policies and so on, since my roles system is quite simple. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

@Julio Kirk  You can use the **[Voyager](https://voyager.readme.io/docs/what-is-voyager)** package.

Voyager is simply an admin for your Laravel app. Whatever you want your app to do on the front-end is completely up to you. You are in control of your application and you can use Voyager to make your life easier by adding data, editing users, creating menus, and many other administrative tasks.

Your requirement is fully completed in this project.

Answer (score 0):

As one user can have only one of three roles you don't really need to separate roles from permissions - just add role cell to your users table or if you can't modify it create new one with id - role pairs.

After that you simply use middleware with with parameter:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#middleware-parameters

to determine if user is allowed to visit current route.

Besides that this post will be answer to you:
[Laravel 5.4 redirection to custom url after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Actually, an user can have one, two or three roles. For example, it would be common for the admin to be a professor at the same time. In this case, I'd like the user to be able to choose which profile to view at the moment, Professor or Admin. This choice is presented on a page I call "identities" in the form of flexible boxes that are links to the profiles.