# Laravel default login redirection not working

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, redirect

Hi I have installed the Laravel 5.7 version and when I go to authenticated url it redirects to the login page, but after login it redirects to home page.

This authenticated url could be any url that is authenticated with laravel `auth` middleware.

Here is my example router resource code for the url:

```
Route::namespace('User')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware('auth')->resource('delivery', 'DeliveryController');
});
```

The default behavior is when we try to go to a authenticated url it should redirect to login and after login it should redirect back to the authenticated url.

Ex:

*delivery->login->delivery*

*customer->login->customer*

But the problem is whatever url I call it redirects to home page (which is the `$redirectTo` in `LoginController`) after login. I have installed the passport for API authentication. Can anyone suggest me where should I start looking?

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: @WebArtisan I want it to go ```/delivery``` url, not home page

Comment: So simple you want to redirect to delivery page after login is that your question ?

Comment: Please follow this threat for more understanding https://stackoverflow.com/q/42177044/5928015

Comment: @ViperTecPro question edited please check.

Answer (score 1):

In your default Login Controller, which resides in app -> Http -> Controllers -> Auth, there is a protected property called `$redirectTo`, make it to wherever you want user to get redirected after login. By default is the homepage.

In your case, you should change it to `/delivery`

If you are using passport means your Laravel installation is working as API, in that case the redirection is a work of whatever front end you are using.

With help of Passport, you can authenticate user, generate access token and send it back to the front end as JSON or any other format based upon your app.

And then based upon that response, you manage redirects from your front end.

The `$redirectTo` property will help only if you use the default authorization mechanism of Laravel.

So I believe you are confusing Laravel authorization with Passport Authentication process which are two very different things.

Please make a further edit to your question and provide details of your app and what you are trying to achieve and why are you using Passport in order for anyone here to help you in the right direction.

Makes sense?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: In your default Login Controller, which resides in app -> Http -> Controllers -> Auth, there is a protected property called $redirectTo, make it to wherever you want user to get redirected after login. By default is the homepage. - This property is applied if you directly go into login page, if you are coming from auth middleware the default redirection should be the previous authenticated url.

Comment: If you are using passport means your Laravel installation is working as API, in that case the redirection is a work of whatever front end you are using. - I just want to know whether passport conflicts default authentication.

Comment: In your case, you should change it to /delivery - I have lot of urls like that, not delivery and again, the default behavior should be redirecting it to the appropriate page.