# In laravel project how can I have different redirect for users and admins after they had login?

Tags: laravel, authentication

At user's table I add an column called(level) and now I wanna redirect users with level admin to paneladmin view after login and redirect users with level user to home view.

Comment: use `if(){}else{}` based on user roles

Comment: already solved please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in controller before redirect user you must check level of user and redirect user according to level of user.

if use a default auth in laravel 6 go to this path => *`your_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/llluminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php`*

find `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)` and modify bottom code with your project and put inside `authenticated` method :

```
if($user->level == 'admin') {
  return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
} else if($user->level == 'user'){
  return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
}
```

for more detail you can see this question : [Laravel 5.4 redirection to custom url after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides loigin redirect functionality out of the box. All you need to do is to modify Laravel's built in `redirectIfAuthenticated` middleware. So, you would have something like this:

```
public function handle( $request, Closure $next, $guard = null ) {
        if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) { //check if user is authenthicated
            $user = Auth::user();
            switch ( $user->level ) {
                case 'admin':
                    return redirect( )->route('admin');
                    break;
                case 'user':
                    return redirect()->route('user');
                    break;
                default:
                    return redirect( '/' );
            }
        }
        return $next( $request );
    }
```

So in this example, we're going through authenticated user's roles, to determine which page he should be redirected. This is a basic example of how to handle different roles for users, but it should give you a glimpse on how this stuff works and help you in resolving your issue. You can read more about Laravel's in built auth system on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication), where you can find more methods that handle the logic functionality. Hope that this can help you, and lead you in the right direction.