# Laravel. How to pass an argument to the redirectTo() function in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm building a page with 2 logins. So every login has its own blade file. The redirect happens in the LoginController.php i replace this  `protected $redirectTo = '/page1';` with

```
function redirectTo(){
        if(true){
            return '/page1';
        } else {
            return '/page2';
        }
    }
```

It works, that means that it doesn't throw an error. But how can I pass an argument to this function and at which place/file this function is being called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4 redirection to custom url after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177044/laravel-5-4-redirection-to-custom-url-after-login)

Comment: No. Cause the redirect should be depend on the way which login (1 or 2) the user useses, not which role the user has. -> 1 user. 2 logins. 2 redirects. So the idea is to pass some value in the submit form, to this function, but i can't figure it out, how and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a hidden input field in both your forms as

> **form1:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="page1">
```

> **form2:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="page2">
```

Now in `LoginController`

```
 use \Illuminate\Http\Request; // add this line

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
        {


         if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password'), 'verified' => 1])) {
            // Authentication passed...

            if($request->input("page") == "page1") {
               return redirect()->intended('page1');
             } else {
               return redirect()->intended('page2');
             }

        }

        }
```

Comment: I don't want to use role, cause if user1 uses login1 -> page1 if user1 uses login2 -> page2. So the redirect option must imo be in the blade file? or some where else, but i've no idea how to implement it :-(

Comment: @dualpeter I have updated my answer. Please check now

Comment: Fantastic!!! It's working out of the box. I can't believe it. Thank you very much. (✿◠‿◠).

Answer (score 0):

Create a function called `authenticated()` insdide your `LoginController.php`, then create your own implementation base on what you need to do.

Example:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
  if ($user->role == 'Administrator') {
     return redirect('/admin-page');
  } else if($user->role == 'Guest') {
     return redirect('/guest-page');
  }
  abort(401);
}
```